# Find acronyms unless followed by open bracket character (

Tags: vba, ms-word, wildcard

I have a macro that uses wildcards to find acronyms in a Word document.

I want to 'unhighlight' that acronym if it is followed by a (.
For example, my content might say "BRB (be right back)" so BRB would not be highlighted. But, LOL would be highlighted if (laughing out loud) does not immediately follow the text.

I am trying to avoid false positives. Is there way I can exclude the 'BRB' results?

```vb
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = "<[A-Z]{2,}>"
With .Replacement
  .Text = "^&"
  .ClearFormatting
  .Highlight = True
End With
```

Comment: You do three sets of replaces. The first replaces BRB ( with BRB XX, you then do yourfind and replace that unhighlights, you then replace BRB XX with BRB (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Sub HighlightAcronyms()

    Dim rng As Range, r2 As Range

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    Set r2 = ActiveDocument.Content

    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<[A-Z]{2,}>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Format = False

        Do While .Execute
            'look two characters past the found acroynm
            r2.Start = rng.End + 1
            r2.End = rng.End + 3
            Debug.Print rng.Text, r2.Text

            'highlight if r2 has a "(" otherwise clear highlight
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = IIf(r2.Text Like "*(*", _
                                        wdAuto, wdYellow)


        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```